# Effective way to compute cosine similarity for sparse tensors in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, tensor

I have a list of unit **tensors(length = 1)**. This list contains **~20 000** such tensors. Tensors have **~3 000**  dimensions but are very sparse. Only **x (0 < x < 1)** dimensions are **not 0**. And I need to compute cosine similarity between all these tensors. What is the most effective way to do this? *(This is not an NLP task, but my solution looks similar to **word2Vect** approach, that's why I have added NLP tag. My tensor has more dimensions than **word2vec** and it is more sparse)*

Comment: The integer range you describe ($0 < x < 1$) is empty.

Answer (score 1):

### Refer below site for sklearn cosine_similarity function

```
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html
```

## In python

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cos_sim = cosine_similarity(vector1,vector2)
```

Comment: Thanks. How to use it with a sparse array? Can't find example.

Comment: And what are vector1,vector2? If just numpy arrays then that would be computationally ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

SciKit-Learn's [`cosine_similarity`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) is your friend:

```py
from scipy import sparse
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# example test:
T = sparse.rand(4, 3, 0.9)
cosine_similarity(T)

# full run (tensor as described in question):
T = sparse.rand(20000, 3000)
%time cosine_similarity(T)
```

Takes about 4.4 seconds on my machine.

```
# staying sparse:
%time cosine_similarity(T, dense_output=False)
```

Takes less than 2 seconds on my machine (i.e., around a factor 2 speedup).